# How do I get input from Spring Book REST API

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

Im trying to create a desktop app but for contacting database and stuff like this I want to use a REST API but this is my first one and im having some issues I don't know how to make it so when the user send the following json

```
{
    "Password": "test"
}
```

it will use that as the the `password` variable

This is my code

APIContollers class

```
package com.AnonyomailREST.example.rest.Controller;

import com.AnonyomailREST.example.rest.Models.User;
import com.AnonyomailREST.example.rest.Repo.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class APIControllers {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value={"/login/{username}", "xyz"}, method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.GET})
    public String login(@RequestParam String password, @PathVariable String username){



            String password = PASSWORD FROM JSON THAT USER SENDS;
            System.out.println(password);
            return("nothing");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Unmitigated so I want to be able to pass a variable through a JSON (the var is password)

Comment: @Unmitigated Like I want It so a user could go and used this json to the URL 
{
    "password": "test"
}

and then it would run that with everything else inside the program

Comment: Maybe you can remove things that are not relevant to the question. The problem is just reading the password from the request, not the database-related stuff, right?

Comment: @thinkgruen I guess

Comment: May be read this spring [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/)?

Comment: @aksappy I did but im having trouble with it thats why im here

Comment: Okay, see how the objects are used in the tutorial. Instead of using RequestParam, an object of Employee is used and annotated with RequestBody. This tells Spring Boot to parse and map the incoming json. You have not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow a `@RestController` accept a JSON payload, we can use a POJO with the attributes exactly as the expected JSON payload's keys.

```java
@RequestMapping(value={"/login/{username}", "xyz"}, method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.GET})
    public String login(@RequestBody Password password){
            String password = password.getPassword();
            System.out.println(password);
            return("nothing");
        }
    }
```

```java
class Password {
   private String Password;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Spring boot uses jackson behind the scenes to map the json payload to an object/pojo. You probably don't even need @RequestBody, but the tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) is mentioning it, so I am keeping it.

Please test this.

Side note(s)

1. Do not send passwords as plain text over HTTP. Use TLS/HTTPS.
2. GET is a HTTP verb used to request a resource and should not include data.

Edit - updated option 1 to specify TLS.

Comment: The comment you left above worked perfect thank you so much

Comment: how would I go about not sending the passwords as plain text do I make some kind of encrypter in the REST API or the actual app. I feel like I should do It in the actual app but im going to make my app open source so I feel like it would be pointless and I feel like I shouldn't do it in the REST because it would need a plain text password to go through it before it could actually encrypt it

Comment: See whether TLS is an option, and it does not have to be an application specific implementation. In the setup & security doc, you can add this.

Comment: I will be using SSL/TLS if thats what you mean

Comment: Great, that's all I wanted to say. Sorry the message was unclear earlier. I have updated it for more clarity.